# Relacionamento 1:N utilizando EF usando Data Anotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando fazer o mapeamento entre essas duas classes, onde em campeonato eu tenho uma lista de todas etapas relacionada ao campeonato

Segue as classes,

```
[Table("ETAPA")]
public class Etapa
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("ETAPA_NUMERO")]
    public int EtapaNumero { get; set; }
    [Column("DATA_EVENTO")]
    public DateTime DataEvento { get; set; }
    [Column("CIDADE")]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    [Column("STATUS")]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    [Column("FKID_CAMP")] //minha FK**
    public int IdCamp { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdCamp")]
    public virtual Campeonato Campeonato { get; set; }
}
```

e a

```
[Table("CAMPEONATO")]
public class Campeonato
{
    public Campeonato()
    {
        Etapas = new HashSet<Etapa>();                
    }
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("DESCRICAO")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    [Column("ANO")]
    public int Ano { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<Etapa> Etapas { get; set; }

}
```

Preciso saber como fazer esse relacionamento utilizando EF 6.0

Comment: Já está feito o relacionamento. Tem alguma coisa que não está funcionando corretamente?

Comment: A propriedade 'Etapas' está vindo nula, mas existe dados na base

Comment: Qual o código que você está usando para obter Etapas? E Campeonatos?

Comment: Sorry man !!!, faltava o include na chamada, Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conforme dúvida esclarecida por comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199798/relacionamento-1n-utilizando-ef-usando-data-anotation/199803#comment409978_199798), não há qualquer problema com o mapeamento em si, que está correto. Ao trazer as etapas de um campeonato, é recomendado apressar a carga usando [`.Include()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var campeonato = db.Campeonatos
                   .Include(c => c.Etapas)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Remova também o código abaixo, que está afetando a carga preguiçosa:

```
public Campeonato()
{
    Etapas = new HashSet<Etapa>();                
}
```